# PostgreSQL: Scan relevant partitions only with subquery

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, postgresql-12

I have a table `foundation.data` which is partitioned over an `asset_id` with hash partitioning.

Whenever I do a query such as

```
with deleted_unprocessed_data as (
    delete from foundation.unprocessed_ids d
    where id = any(select id from foundation.unprocessed_ids up order by up.asset_id, up.data_point_timestamp asc limit 1000)
    returning id, asset_id, data_point_timestamp
)

, ids_to_process as 
(
    insert into foundation.processed_ids select * from deleted_unprocessed_data
    returning id, asset_id
)

select jh.asset_id, 
    min(jh.data_point_timestamp) as minborder,
    max(jh.data_point_timestamp) as maxborder
    from 
    (
        select id, asset_id, data_point_timestamp FROM
        foundation.DATA fd 
        where id = any(select id from ids_to_process)
        and fd.asset_id = any(select asset_id from ids_to_process)
    ) jh
    
    group by asset_id;
```

the explain will show that it accesses all partitions:

```
...
->  Append  (cost=0.42..1822.75 rows=256 width=20) (actual time=0.285..0.617 rows=1 loops=1000)
      ->  Index Scan using asset_id_hash_0_id_idx on asset_id_hash_0 fd  (cost=0.42..7.10 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1000)
            Index Cond: (id = ids_to_process.id)
      ->  Index Scan using asset_id_hash_1_id_idx on asset_id_hash_1 fd_1  (cost=0.42..6.66 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1000)
            Index Cond: (id = ids_to_process.id)
            ...
      ->  Index Scan using asset_id_hash_72_id_idx on asset_id_hash_72 fd_72  (cost=0.43..8.35 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1000)
            Index Cond: (id = ids_to_process.id)
            ...
      ->  Index Scan using asset_id_hash_255_id_idx on asset_id_hash_255 fd_255  (cost=0.42..6.87 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1000)
            Index Cond: (id = ids_to_process.id)
```

How do force the planner to only access the relevant partitions?

Comment: Your query is clearly artificial, since it does not do anything useful. You have to modify the query to get what you want, but without knowing the actual query that causes your problem we cannot give advice on that. In the form it has now, it cannot use partition pruning.

Comment: Thanks for your hints @LaurenzAlbe! I edited my question and was able to find a solution myself. If you have any pointers on that, I am very happy :)

Answer (score 0):

The subquery is accessing only one partition:

```
 ->  Hash  (cost=145.14..145.14 rows=200 width=4)
        ->  Group  (cost=0.00..143.14 rows=200 width=4)
            Group Key: asset_7800_1.asset_id
            ->  Seq Scan on asset_7800 asset_7800_1  (cost=0.00..135.11 rows=3209 width=4)
                Filter: (asset_id = 7800)
```

The outer query on the other hand is accessing all partitions. I think this is because the planner can't be sure that the subquery will return rows belonging to only one partition.

Don't think there is an obvious way to do this unfortunately. Try running the explain with the `ANALYZE` option. That will tell you what Postgres actually did and then you might see that it actually only ended up scanning one partition.

Comment: thanks a lot for your hints! Thanks to this and @laurenz Albe I was able to actually find a solution myself

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here but do not understand the dynamics behind so happy for hints on your side as to why this changes so much.

I used a join instead:

```
with deleted_unprocessed_data as (
    delete from foundation.unprocessed_ids d
    where id = any(select id from foundation.unprocessed_ids up order by up.asset_id, up.data_point_timestamp asc limit 1000
                --    case 
                --          when numberOfItems<1000 then numberOfItems
                --          when numberOfItems>999 then 1000 
                --    end
                    )
    returning id, asset_id, data_point_timestamp
)
, ids_to_process as 
(
    insert into foundation.processed_ids select * from deleted_unprocessed_data
    returning id, asset_id
)

select jh.asset_id, 
    min(jh.data_point_timestamp) as minborder,
    max(jh.data_point_timestamp) as maxborder
    from 
    (
        select fd.id, fd.asset_id, fd.data_point_timestamp FROM
        foundation.DATA fd
        **join** ids_to_process itp
        on fd.asset_id = itp.asset_id
        and fd.id = itp.id
    ) jh
    
    group by asset_id;
```

Then I get the following explain analyze which specifies that all index scans but on one partition were never executed:

```
...
    ->  Append  (cost=0.42..1823.39 rows=256 width=20) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=1 loops=1000)
        ->  Index Scan using asset_id_hash_0_id_idx on asset_id_hash_0 fd  (cost=0.42..7.10 rows=1 width=20) (never executed)
                Index Cond: (id = itp.id)
                Filter: (itp.asset_id = asset_id)
        ->  Index Scan using asset_id_hash_1_id_idx on asset_id_hash_1 fd_1  (cost=0.42..6.67 rows=1 width=20) (never executed)
                Index Cond: (id = itp.id)
                Filter: (itp.asset_id = asset_id)
    ...
        ->  Index Scan using asset_id_hash_72_id_idx on asset_id_hash_72 fd_72  (cost=0.43..8.35 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=1000)
                Index Cond: (id = itp.id)
                Filter: (itp.asset_id = asset_id)
    ...
        ->  Index Scan using asset_id_hash_255_id_idx on asset_id_hash_255 fd_255  (cost=0.42..6.87 rows=1 width=20) (never executed)
                Index Cond: (id = itp.id)
                Filter: (itp.asset_id = asset_id)
```